# Heroku Deployment Error w/ Compojure: "Could not locate leiningen/core/classpath__init.class"

Tags: heroku, clojure, web-deployment, compojure

I refactored my light webapp to now use ***[Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure)***. Everything works fine locally. However, my problem occurs when I deploy to ***[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)***. I'm trying to run it with `lein ring server-headless $PORT`, but am getting the error below. My Procfile is `web: lein ring server-headless $PORT`, due to ***[this issue](https://github.com/sebasoga/conway-cljs/commit/ff48e51e235b7d20dea9d59c0e4c964ada46089a)***. But still no luck. Any ideas?

```
    2013-06-25T02:38:15.671118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `lein ring server-headless 17731`
    2013-06-25T02:38:16.350715+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.684531+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.683953+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/classpath__init.class or leiningen/core/classpath.clj on classpath:  (server.clj:1)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685445+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.684682+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.684956+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685581+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.684821+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685221+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685714+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685976+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.686270+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685089+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.686403+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.685846+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.686106+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.686587+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.686727+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.686860+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:544)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.687027+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:4892)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.687158+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.687292+00:00 app[web.1]:    at leiningen.ring$eval68$loading__4414__auto____69.invoke(ring.clj:1)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.687425+00:00 app[web.1]:    at leiningen.ring$eval68.invoke(ring.clj:1)
    2013-06-25T02:38:19.687557+00:00 app[web.1]:    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this problem cropped up in several places. [This post](http://www.bkumar.co.uk/2012/07/30/leiningen-plugin-to-generate-intellij-idea-project-files-loving-clojure/) (and [this one](http://www.raynes.me/logs/irc.freenode.net/leiningen/2011-12-07.txt)) was informative.

I basically stumbled across the [Heroku Buildpack: Clojure](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure). This gives some interesting configuration directions. Specifically, I had to

- set a minimum lein version. `:min-lein-version "2.0.0"`
- require JDK 7 and `echo "java.runtime.version=1.7" > system.properties`
- added the ring servlet lib: `[ring/ring-servlet "1.2.0-RC1"]`

And now everything is copasetic. Hope this helps someone.